# What are "delegated permissions" in the context of an Azure Active directory Application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

From below, what I infer is when the application is configured with Delegated Permissions it makes all requests on behalf of the signed-in user.

So, under Delegated Permissions, again we have "Access the directory as the signed-in user" option listed. What does this actually do?

> Application Permissions: Your client application needs to access the
>   Web API directly as itself (no user context). This type of permission
>   requires administrator consent and is also not available for Native
>   client applications.
>
> Delegated Permissions: Your client application needs to access the Web
>   API as the signed-in user, but with access limited by the selected
>   permission. This type of permission can be granted by a user unless
>   the permission is configured as requiring administrator consent.

Answer (score 6):

> So, under Delegated Permissions, we have "Access the directory as the
>   signed-in user" option listed. What does this actually do?

In very simple words, the application essentially impersonates you (or the logged in user) in case of delegated permissions.

To give you an example, let's say you created a web application in your Azure AD with delegated permissions to access Azure Service Management API. Now when you login into this application and try to access your Azure resources (storage accounts, VMs etc.), the application will only be able to do things you're granted permission to do in that Azure subscription. For example, if you're in `Reader` role in your Azure subscription (i.e. you can't create/update/delete resources). If you try to create a resource through your application you will get   an error back because the application is impersonating you.

Comment: Ok. What if I am remove the "Access the directory as the signed-in user". Which credentials it will use to hit the API?

Comment: My understanding is that in this case the application won't be able to access the directory because you have not assigned any permissions to the application.

Comment: so this is the same as allowing offiine access?

Answer (score 1):

Delegated permissions require a user to login to Azure AD and present the resulting authentication token to your application. Your application can make calls by passing your client id, secret (if applicable) *and* the user's authentication token. Your application's effective permissions will be the lowest combination of the user and your application. For example, if your application has been granted read/write to a resource but the user only has read, your effective permissions are read. The same is true if the user has read/write but the application only has read.

Application permissions do not require a user to login. Just your client id and secret are enough. If you do not have application permissions and attempt to access the api without also presenting an authenticated user's token you will receive 401 errors.